# How to make a vertical separator in a Windows Forms Application (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

For a project, I have to make a Windows Forms Application that makes a Mandelbrotfigure. Now i want to add a vertical separator between the UI on the left and the Figure on the right (See Picture). Any idea on how to do that?

[image: Windows Forms Application]

Comment: The GUI Designer only show an empty form..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is too late to answer this, but for the ease of anyone who ends up here searching:
As `Line control` deprecated, **just use a `Label control`** with `AutoSize = false` and `Size = 1,xx` with any `BackColor` you like your line to be.

> Replace `xx` in the Size with actual height.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class VertSep : Control
{
    private Color lineColor;
    private Pen linePen;

    public VertSep()
    {
        this.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
        SetStyle( ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true );
    }

    public Color LineColor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lineColor;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lineColor = value;

            this.linePen = new Pen( this.lineColor, 1 );
            this.linePen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;

            Refresh();
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( disposing && this.linePen != null )
        {
            this.linePen.Dispose();
            this.linePen = null;
        }

        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }

    protected override void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs e )
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;
        int x = this.Width / 2;

        g.DrawLine( linePen, x, 0, x, this.Height );

        base.OnPaint( e );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to move all your contents inside a [`SplitContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx). This container contains two panels and a divider. You'll have to place the controls on one side and the image on the other panel.

In your particular case you'll probably have to start over.

Using the designer you should set the SplitContainer's [`Dock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.dock(v=vs.110).aspx) property on *Fill*. You can move the divider by selecting it and dragging (this is only possible if you have the SplitContainer selected). Once the divider is in the right place, it might be wise to set the [`FixedPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.fixedpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) property to the left panel as you probably don't want this panel to grow when maximizing.
It's still possible to move the divider in the application as long as the property [`IsSplitterFixed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.issplitterfixed(v=vs.110).aspx) is set to *False*.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom Separator control just for this purpose. You can install it via the NuGet Package Manager Console:

`Install-Package ALMSTWKND -Version 1.0.0`

Just drag and drop it onto your Form from the Toolbox after installation.